# I am facing issue in joining three tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

There are 3 tables `party`, `party_b`, `address`.

First I need to join `party` and `party_B` to get `phone`, `area_code`, `source_object`, `system` because `source_object` and `system` are not present in `party` table, and compare the output with columns `src_object`, `phone`, `area_cd` in `address` table.

`address` table is in different database.

How to compare those two results? I have tried different ways but unable to get the output

Comment: Post your best try.

Comment: I need the matching records from address and party table

Comment: Remember: we can't see your screen, we don't know your project - so please **SHOW US** the table structure, sample data, your best effort, and what output you're expecting from that sample data

Answer (score 0):

Generally should be no different to joining tables from the same database. Just make sure ou specify table names fully, including database name and schema.

Should look something like this:

```
select * from Firstdb.dbo.party left outer join Firstdb.dbo.party_b on ...
left outer join Otherdb.dbo.address on
Otherdb.dbo.address.src_object=FirstDb.dbo.party_b.source_object and 
Otherdb.dbo.address.area_code=FirstDb.dbo.party_b.area_cd and 
Otherdb.dbo.address.address=FirstDb.dbo.party_b.address
```